# Codename one project Run issue after it was running

Tags: codenameone

i got an issue suddenly while running my Codename one project,

com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator class wasn't found in project
i clean & build the project multiple times and also restarted the netbeans but issue is still there.

also i didn't change the class path or anything
and other projects are working fine,

any one can help please,

Running Results: 
[image]

Compiling Properties:
[image]

Run Properties: 
[image]

Project Properties : 
[image]

[image]
Build output:

```
ant -f E:\\Cross_Platform_Course\\NetBeansProjects\\Kaizen-Gate -Dnb.internal.action.name=build jar
No GUI Entries available
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\build
Updating property file: E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\build\classes
Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
        code size and wider device support
Created dir: E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\build\tmp
Compiling 3 source files to E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\build\tmp
Created dir: E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\build\empty
Created dir: E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 3 source files to E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\build\classes
Copying 1 file to E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\dist
Copying 1 file to E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\build
Not copying library E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\override , it's a directory.
Not copying library E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\lib\impl\cls , it's a directory.
Not copying library E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\lib\impl\stubs , it's a directory.
Not copying library E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\native\internal_tmp , it's a directory.
Copy libraries to E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\dist\lib.
Cannot fix dependencies for: E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\dist\lib\JavaSE.jar
Building jar: E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\dist\Kaizen-Gate.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "E:\Cross_Platform_Course\NetBeansProjects\Kaizen-Gate\dist\Kaizen-Gate.jar"
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Please provide your build log together with the question

Comment: Build log updated with question, the issue while run i got popup that there is no main class.

Comment: Well then, is there? Do you have an accessible main method?

Comment: it's a codename one project , so the main class is automatically generated , i have MyApplication.java class that have the init(), start(), stop() methods.

Answer (score 0):

The class is defined in `JavaSE.jar` which is in the root of the project. If you changed or removed that jar or changed the classpath from the default which should look like the screenshots below this will happen:

[image]

Notice `JavaSE.jar` is mentioned below. The presence and order of the entries is important.

[image]

The run section should look like this, notice that the main class of your application should be in the arguments section

[image]

Comment: I updated the libraries properties and it looks ok !!

Comment: That comment was very unclear, when you write "looks OK" I assume this works... Check that JavaSE.jar is a valid jar archive and has the `Simulator.class` file within it. Notice that the output you posted is output for build and not the output for running which is what you are complaining about

Comment: Simulator.class file is existing in JavaSE.jar in path : JavaSE.jar\com\codename1\impl\javase       and after running there is no output , it just show dialog saying there is no main class.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of the run and compiling sections in the dialog too?

Comment: Added the run section screenshot, it seems something broke for you there